# Javascript / JQuery how to loop through all html elements with attribute aria-invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

I have some dynamically ajax generated form:

```
<form id="formThatWillBeReplcaedViaAjax">

  <div class="col-main">

    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-group">
         <input id="some_unique_generated_id_27362"  aria-invalid="false" ... >
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-group">
         <input id="some_unique_generated_id_27363"  aria-invalid="false" ... >
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-group">
         <input id="some_unique_generated_id_27364"  aria-invalid="false" ... >
       </div>
    </div>

   </div>

</form>
```

I have some animation function (`loader()`  )  and  the   function  that replaces the current form with the next form (  `requestNextForm()`   )

I want to  check by looping through form with pure JS or JQuery to check if all attributes `aria-invalid` are equal to `"false"`.

If they are, then let the `loader()` load the animation and only then request the next form via `requestNextForm()`.

How can I do it with JQuery or JS or maybe Lodash ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Native JS `document.querySelectorAll('[aria-invalid="false"]')`, jQuery  `$('[aria-invalid="false"]')`

Comment: Satpal, thank you so much!  So fast!!!! :)

Comment: @Satpal: that only return elements whose attribute `aria-invalid` has value `false` and does not handle the context where there may be elements with `aria-invalid` that have a value other than `false`...

Comment: Satpal, but when I do document.querySelectorAll('[aria-invalid="false"]')  it returns array with only 1 element,  but I have 3 of them.   Why is that so?

Comment: @Satpal: ah, seems to have helped the OP, so fair enough :)

Comment: JavaJedi: check out my answer...

Comment: @Satpal: I'm guessing in his code, aria-invalid isn't all set to false, hence my answer which deals with this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- get all inputs with the attribute aria-invalid whose value is not "false" using `querySelectorAll`
- usr the selector `'input[aria-invalid]:not([aria-invalid="false"])'` which translates to: return all input elements that have an attribute aria-invalid whose value is not "false"
- if the above query returns any matches, you know that not all inputs with aria-invalid are "false"

Here's what the code could look like:

```
var ariaInvalidNotFalse = document.querySelectorAll('input[aria-invalid]:not([aria-invalid="false"])');

if(ariaInvalidNotFalse.length > 0){
  // Some elements have aria-invalid
  // but with a value that is not false
} else {
  // All inputs with aria-invalid 
  // have it set to "false"
  // Call loader() etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pineda, works like charm :)     With your solution now piece of cake to implement the thing i wanted :)

Comment: and thank you for jsfiddle!   Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: My focus was some where else hence just pointed the OP in a direction rather than posting complete answer. Glad you helped him +1. It would be nice if you could have added description rather than inline comments

Comment: @Satpal: understood dude and thanks. Only wanted to point out the specifics in case the OP expected it to work as suggested :)

Comment: @JavaJedi: Glad you found my answer useful!